# How does ISP's DNS works?

Tags: dns, dhcp, isp

Computers can connect websites using ISP's default DNS even if a DNS is not configured. How do clients or the router know the address of the DNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DNS server is either specified in case of a static IP configuration or retreived in case of a DHCP retrieved ip configuration.

In most cases, when you connect to the ISP, it will simply give you your IP Address and specify the DNS servers you can use. If you use a router, the router will then forward DNS requests to those DNS servers or places those DNS servers directly in the DHCP configuration of your LAN clients.

So it does matter how you configure things, but in any case, either your ISP tells you what the DNS servers are going to be and you need to set it up, or when they use a DHCP server on their end, it will be transferred when your client gets the ip and dns servers at connect.